# Allow to use rsync hyperlinks

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

When talking about Gentoo Linux *(both in answers and in questions)* I often end-up putting links to their mirrors which use the rsync protocol.

Such links are very common on http://www.gentoo.org/ to let people download with rsync enabled browsers.

I can understand why all protocols aren't allowed on Stack Exchange, but this one is definitely inoffensive and have full place in Gentoo discussions on Stack OverFlow.

Following is an example of rsync hyperlink:

```
[Here's a link example](rsync://ftp6.linux.cz/pub/linux/gentoo/distfiles/)
```

and it's result :
Here's a link example