# Support for unusual URLs

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

From the question on SuperUser, [Google Chrome “Unable to connect to Internet”](https://superuser.com/questions/807995/google-chrome-unable-to-connect-to-internet), I tried to make a hyperlink out of this:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

It didn't work:

> [image]

It would be nice if it did though. How much work would it be to add `chrome://` as a trigger for a link, in much the same way as `ftp://`, `https://` and `http://` do?

However, I *do* realise that this could open the floodgates for all sorts of weird and wonderful URL support requests.

Comment: Related: [Allow to use rsync hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230892/21960)

Comment: Related: [Support for obscure protocols in markdown link syntax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103624/21960)